# CSS class apply to body background

Tags: css, background

Using css (not a inline one, but external stylesheet) how do i override the styles applied to body background only for a single page. I right now got this and this does not work

```
body{background: url("../../images/mybg.png") repeat-x scroll 0 0 #7CC2FF;height: 100%}
body.index{background-color:#4466A7!Important}
```

I want the body background to change on index page only, so i used js hack as below

```
if(location.href.indexOf("index.aspx") != -1){
    $("body").addClass("index");
}
```

but seems the background image is still used and has higher precedence. How do i remove the previous style to apply the overrided styles

#### Solution

so finally this is how it is solved

```
body{#4466A7 background: url("../../images/mybg.png") repeat-x scroll 0 0}
body.index{background-image:none !important}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
body.index{background-color:#4466A7 !important}
```

Note the space between the color and !important and capitalisation used on important.

Comment: actually i had also to apply `background-image:none` to get this done. thanks please add this to your answer to mark yours as answer

Comment: That seems a little redundant. If you feel I contributed to your answer that's fine, if you prefer DmitryB's answer that's fine too.

Answer (score 1):

```
body.index{background-image: none}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this very easily through css like you need all pages with red background and index page with yellow background see the mentioned below example with css & HTML code :-

```
body {
background:red;    
}

#index {
background:yellow;   
}


<body id="index"> (!--for yellow color index page--!) 
adfadfasf    
</body>

<body> (!--for red color all pages--!) 
adfadfasf    
</body>
```

**or see the fiddle:-** 
http://jsfiddle.net/n6y4q/